# VueJS: Sending data value from child component to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue compoment rendering inside `index.vue`

In **index.vue** we have some data **:**

```
data(){
      return {
      splashIsActive: true,
      tutorialIsActive: false,
      gameIsActive: false
      }
    }
```

and the component inside **index.vue** **:**

```
<SplashBox v-if="splashIsActive"/>
```

Then, if we go to splashBox there's a button.

```
<button @click="debug">....
```

Is there any way to create a method that after clicking the button sends, or changes splashIsActive to `false`, instead of true as it is stored in index.vue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by emitting an event from the `button`.

```
<button @click="$emit('updateSplashState', false)">...</button>
```

Then, You can capture this event in parent component.

```
<SplashBox v-if="splashIsActive" @updateSplashState="splashIsActive = $event"/>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('splashbox', {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('update-splash-state', false)">Update</button>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    splashIsActive: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <SplashBox v-if="splashIsActive" @update-splash-state="splashIsActive = $event"></SplashBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`emit`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) an event to the parent.

```
<button @click="debug">....


methods: {
   debug() {
     this.$emit('setSplashUnActive', false)
   }
}
```

In the parent component.

```
<SplashBox v-if="splashIsActive" @setSplashUnActive="setSplashUnActive" />


methods: {
   setSplashUnActive(value) {
      this.splashIsActive = value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prop to pass the value from parent to child. Within the child component on pressing the key you can emit an event to update its value. To do this it is necessary to indicate the prop as sync:

```js
<SplashBox: splashUnActive.sync="initValue"></Checkbox>
```

and then inside SplashBox on click of the button:

```js
this.$emit('update:splashUnActive.', newValue)
```